# In Vue 3 how do I reference a local resource when using a UI Framework (without "@")?

Tags: vuejs3, vite, chakra-ui, element-plus

I am accustomed to using the "@" character in Vue 3 so the location will still be referenced after Vite build, as in the following example:

```
<img src="@/assets/picture.jpg" />
```

With custom components from UI Frameworks, I can't figure out how to reference my images anymore! The "@" no longer works, since it is rendering out the custom component.

Element Plus example:

```
<el-image src="@/assets/picture.jpg" />
```

I tried using various permutations without the "@" sign. I couldn't readily find the answer in Vue 3 docs or docs for Element Plus or Chakra UI frameworks, and it is a hard question to search for here.

Comment: Not sure to fully understand the issue but you could use `.. /.. /assets` (relative paths).

Comment: @kissu that gives me 404 error, same with regular `../`, and same if I declare the url as a const in the javascript and v-bind to src property of el-image.

Comment: `../..` was an example of course. You need to put enough of them to actually get your real asset.

Comment: @kissu, so to clarify: the image does load with `../` on an `<img />` but not on the `<el-image />` that is a custom component of the UI framework.

Comment: The issue comes from the component so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out how this can work, but it's hardly a solution

```
<script setup>
import imageUrl from "@/assets/picture.jpg";
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <el-image :src="imageUrl" />
  </div>
</template>
```